# Locking down Docker Registries

Tags: docker

We are using Docker in a banking and finance environment and security is paramount - understanding the provenance of what is in an image is essential.

We do not want developers downloading images from untrusted locations so we have set up an internal registry where we store images we trust.

Developer machines are policy managed so we have the ability to lock down certain configuration or functionality remotely.

I think the answer to my question is "no" - but here goes:

- Is there a way to lock down the Docker registry url to our trusted registry and make it so that it cannot be manually overwritten?

Alternatively,

- Is it possible to stop Docker running images that are not signed with a specified cert? (I think Docker EE might be able to do this.)

Comment: Both strategies won't help if an image contains a vulnerability only discovered after approval/signature.

Comment: @Henry - Thanks. Agree with your comment, but that kind of goes without saying - and does not really address the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with a few customers in both banking and finance domains. What I have seen is a complete lockdown approach with the nodes not able to access the internet. If they really have to use the internet, HTTP_PROXY or HTTPS_PROXY variables are used. All the needed images from the docker hub are mirrored in their private repository. The downside of this every simple image name needs to be prefixed with the registry info.

All the policies of the organization are enforced using the proxy server. Any requests to Docker hub are restricted.